# How to make search page and detail page from a main page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have table with list of books(which is not part of the posts or custom post and it can not controlled by the wp admin side). My requirement is I want book landing page with search options, search result page and detail page of the each book. I have created a page 'books' in admin side which contains the URL www.mydomain.com/books(books landing page) using a custom template. In this landing page there is an option for search books. When I submit the search result, it should go the this URL www.mydomain.com/books/search and display the search result in this page. From this search result I want to move the detail page of the book which should have URL www.mydomain.com/books/search/123 (123 represents the id of the book).

My question is how it is possible to make this URLs (www.mydomain.com/books/search and www.mydomain.com/books/search/123) and which represnts .php file.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you'll have to create a Custom post type called "Book". Then you can add books easily and also you can make the search functionality easily.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't go ahead with the custom post type, Because the the data we have updated via cronjob.